# How to properly pass a scipy.sparse CSR matrix to a cython function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, sparse-matrix

I need to pass a scipy.sparse CSR matrix to a cython function. How do I specify the type, as one would for a numpy array?

Comment: do you want to quickly access the values of this matrix? perhaps it is better to pass a `coo_matrix` and use the properties `row`, `col` and `data` to access only the non-zero values, using 1-D array buffers in Cython to give you the fastest access...

Comment: that's precisely what i want. Could you please give me an example of how to do this.

Comment: According the `csr` documentation, the component arrays are `data, indices, indptr`.  The `coo` arrays, `data, row, col` are easier to understand, but the `csr` ones are preferred for most math operations.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example about how to quickly access the data from a `coo_matrix` using the properties `row`, `col` and `data`. The purpose of the example is just to show how to declare the data types and create the buffers (also adding the compiler directives that will usually give you a considerable boost)...

```
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False

import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int32_t cINT32
ctypedef np.double_t cDOUBLE

def print_sparse(m):
    cdef np.ndarray[cINT, ndim=1] row, col
    cdef np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=1] data
    cdef int i
    if not isinstance(m, coo_matrix):
        m = coo_matrix(m)
    row = m.row.astype(np.int32)
    col = m.col.astype(np.int32)
    data = m.data.astype(np.float64)
    for i in range(np.shape(data)[0]):
        print row[i], col[i], data[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on @SaulloCastro's answer, add this function to the `.pyx` file to display the attributes of a `csr` matrix:

```
def print_csr(m):
    cdef np.ndarray[cINT32, ndim=1] indices, indptr
    cdef np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=1] data
    cdef int i
    if not isinstance(m, csr_matrix):
        m = csr_matrix(m)
    indices = m.indices.astype(np.int32)
    indptr = m.indptr.astype(np.int32)
    data = m.data.astype(np.float64)
    print indptr
    for i in range(np.shape(data)[0]):
        print indices[i], data[i]
```

`indptr` does not have the same length as `data`, so can't be printed in the same loop.

To display the `csr` data like `coo`, you can do your own conversion with these iteration lines:

```
    for i in range(np.shape(indptr)[0]-1):
        for j in range(indptr[i], indptr[i+1]):
            print i, indices[j], data[j]
```

I assume you know how to setup and compile a `pyx` file.

Also, what does your `cython` function assume about the matrix?  Does it know about the `csr` format?  The `coo` format?

Or does your `cython` function want a regular `numpy` array?  In that case, we are off on a rabbit trail.  You just need to convert the sparse matrix to an array: `x.toarray()` (or `x.A` for short).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the data directly (without copy) you need to specify the type in the function argument:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
def some_cython_func(np.ndarray[np.double_t] data, np.ndarray[int] indices, np.ndarray[int] indptr):
    #body of of the function
```

Then you may call this function using

```
some_cython_func(M.data, M.indices, M.indptr)
```

where `M` is your `CSR` or `CSC` function.

See [this page](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) for an explanation of passing argument without casting.

Comment: exactly, so what type should I use for a scipy.sparse matrix? The type you defined in your example is a numpy matrix.

Comment: The CSR matrix is represented using three numpy arrays (data, indices and indptr) that are accessible. Here we are passing those arrays to our cython function as a representative of the CSR matrix. You can efficiently reconstruct the CSR matrix inside the cython function from these arrays.