# Is it possible to translate this Python code to Cython?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, cython

I'm actually looking to speed up #2 of this code by as much as possible, so I thought that it might be useful to try Cython. However, I'm not sure how to implement sparse matrix in Cython. Can somebody show how to / if it's possible to wrap it in Cython or perhaps Julia to make it faster?

```python
#1) This part computes u_dict dictionary filled with unique strings and then enumerates them.

import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

full_dict = set(train1.values.ravel().tolist() + test1.values.ravel().tolist() + train2.values.ravel().tolist() + test2.values.ravel().tolist())
print len(full_dict)
u_dict= dict()
for i, q in enumerate(full_dict):
    u_dict[q] = i


shape = (len(full_dict), len(full_dict))
H = sp.lil_matrix(shape, dtype=np.int8)


def load_sparse_csr(filename):
    loader = np.load(filename)
    return csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'], loader['indptr']),
                      shape=loader['shape'])

#2) I need to speed up this part
# train_full is pandas dataframe with two columns w1 and w2 filled with strings

H = load_sparse_csr('matrix.npz')

correlation_train = []
for idx, row in train_full.iterrows():
    if idx%1000 == 0: print idx
    id_1 = u_dict[row['w1']]
    id_2 = u_dict[row['w2']]
    a_vec = H[id_1].toarray() # these vectors are of length of < 3 mil.
    b_vec = H[id_2].toarray()
    correlation_train.append(np.corrcoef(a_vec, b_vec)[0][1])
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295159/how-to-properly-pass-a-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-to-a-cython-function).

Answer (score 0):

While I contributed to [How to properly pass a scipy.sparse CSR matrix to a cython function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295159/how-to-properly-pass-a-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-to-a-cython-function) quite some time ago, I doubt if `cython` is the way to go.  Especially if you don't already have experience with `numpy` and `cython`.  `cython` gives the biggest speedup when you replace iterative calculations with code that it can translate to C without calling `numpy` or other `python` code.  Throw `pandas` into the mix and you have an even bigger learning curve.

And important parts of `sparse` code are already written with `cython`.

Without touching the cython issue I see a couple of problems.

`H` is defined twice:

```
H = sp.lil_matrix(shape, dtype=np.int8)
H = load_sparse_csr('matrix.npz')
```

That's either an oversight, or a failure to understand how Python variables are created and assigned.  The 2nd assignment replaces the first; thus the first does nothing.  In addition the first just makes an empty `lil` matrix.  Such a matrix could be filled iteratively; while not fast it is the intended use of the `lil` format.

The 2nd expression creates a new matrix from data saved in an `npz` file. That involves the `numpy` npz file loaded as well as the basic `csr` matrix creation code.  And since the attributes are already in `csr` format, there's nothing for `cython` touch.

You do have an iteration here - but over a Pandas dataframe:

```
for idx, row in train_full.iterrows():
    id_1 = u_dict[row['w1']]
    a_vec = H[id_1].toarray()
```

Looks like you are picking a particular row of `H` based on a dictionary/array look up.  Sparse matrix indexing is slow compared to dense matrix indexing.  That is, if `Ha = H.toarray()` fits your memory then,

```
a_vec = Ha[id_1,:]
```

will be a lot faster.

Faster selection of rows (or columns) from a sparse matrix has been asked before.  If you could work directly with the sparse data of a row I could recommend something more direct.  But you want a dense array that you can pass to `np.corrcoef`, so we'd have to implement the `toarray` step as well.

[How to read/traverse/slice Scipy sparse matrices (LIL, CSR, COO, DOK) faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013115/how-to-read-traverse-slice-scipy-sparse-matrices-lil-csr-coo-dok-faster)